# Google Apps - Outlook SMTP

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, google-workspace

I am using the standard edition of Google Apps am having issues with sending mail from Outlook 2007. I have followed the Google Instructions to the point, but I receive:

```
550 - No Such User Here
```

As a note:

- Authentication is set up correctly
- TLS and the correct port is in use

I am thinking that it may have something to do with the settings pointing directly to google.

Instead of using `pop.gmail.com` and `smtp.gmail.com`, must I use `pop.mydomain.com` and `smtp.mydomain.com`?

Also, the `pop` settings work 100%. I receive my mail fine.

Comment: Have you set the MX records of your domain to the google servers?

Comment: @Blood - Yeps, all set. There are no duplicate MX records either, only googles.

Comment: I have the same problem.  In outlook 2010, I have one pure gmail account, and two google apps accounts.  All three send mails correctly when you hit "Test Account Settings".  However, If I try and send fro either of the two google apps accounts in outlook, the mail just sits in outbox for ever.  There are no error messages.  The only difference between the working gmail account and the two non working apps accounts is the username - one is user @ gmail.com, the others are user @ mydomain.com etc.  Desperate for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the account correctly ?

The user name should be `userid@domain.tld`

The servers should be
 - `imap.gmail.com` / `pop.gmail.com` ( IMAP/POP3 server )
 - `smtp.gmail.com` ( SMTP server )

Ensure you've enabled SMTP authentication - Under Outgoing Server tab, put a check against `My outgoing server (SMTP) requires authentication` is selected. The radio button `Use same settings as my incoming mail server` should also be selected.

Comment: Yep. All of my settings are set as you've set out.

Comment: @Kyle Thats... weird, just had a look at Google Apps' support firum, most of such issues reported are due to incorrect MX record setup. I'd recommend posting a query at Google Apps Support forum http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps/label?lid=3d42dfb4d7bb262e&hl=en